# AJAX request, getting href attribute for multiple links with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm writing a piece of jQuery that says if .ajaxLink is clicked, then take it's URL and apply it to the ajax call, like so:

```
$(".ajaxLink").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    removePreviousData(); // removes any div that might be loaded in #content
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            $(data).appendTo('#content');
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {},
        complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
            loadedData() // applies some relative animations for loaded content
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

This works fine for the first link that I click on, but since I have multiple links on the same page that use this class, when I click on the second link, it just loads the same data.  How do I get it to apply to each .ajaxLink ( assuming .each(), but can't get that to run ).

Thanks!

Comment: You're using `this`, so it should get the href attribute of the anchor clicked, the problem is probably something else!

Comment: Your code is [working for me](http://jsfiddle.net/BFHyj/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want  `#content` to show only the content of the href of the link clicked you'll have to replace `#content`'s content not append to it.

```
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
        $('#content').html(data);
    },
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was incomplete. I am actually removing the previously loaded data in #content prior to the ajax call. Question has been updated.

Comment: @apttap what does `loadedData()` do

Comment: loadedData() applies some css classes to run some animation and updates the url. code in question updated.

Comment: This isn't the exact right answer, but you were correct. The data wasn't being completely removed, since there were multiple divs being loaded, I didn't see that some were being deleted, while others stayed. Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for the answer.